# Implicit Monad not found with Cats Free foldMap

Tags: scala, free-monad, scala-cats

I have an interpreter with the natural transformation `MyADT ~> MyState`.

I have no problem when `type MyState[A] = State[MyClass, A]`. However, if I have `type MyState[A] = State[MyClass, M[A]]`, where M is any monad, then I get the error: `could not find implicit value parameter M: cats.Monad[MyState]` when calling `foldMap`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Generally, putting a monad into another monad does not give you new monad. You need to use a monad transformer, e.g. `type MyState[A] = StateT[M, MyClass, A]`

Comment: If that other `M` is inside the state, then he needs transformer for `M` not for state.

Comment: The concrete `M` is `OptionT[Future, A]`. However, `type MyState[A] = StateT[OptionT[Future, ?], MyClass, a]` or `OptionT[StateT[Future, MyClass, ?], A]`  give the same problem.

EDIT: wrapping the inner monad transformer in a type alias did the trick. Why does it work like that?

Comment: @DennisVDB That's most like related to the SI2712 issue. On 2.12 you could try compiling with the `-Ypartial-unification` compiler flag.